# Sparsify a kernel/similarity matrix in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I am doing some kernel PCA and want to sparsify a matrix. I did everything in Python and now want to transform my code to matlab for comparison.

I am struggling a little bit at the point where I want to sparsify the kernel matrix. In Python, it is pretty straightforward to me. Here is an example for a simple matrix to show you what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
print('Sparsify a matrix by zeroing all elements but the top 2 values in a row.\n')

A = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[9,8,6,4,5],[3,1,7,8,9]])

print('Before:\n%s\n' %A)

for row in A:
    sort_idx = np.argsort(row)[::-1] # get indexes of sort order (high to low)
    for i in sort_idx[2:]:
        row[i]=0

print('After:\n%s\n' %A)
```

```
Sparsify a matrix by zeroing all elements but the top 2 values in a row.

Before:
[[1 2 3 4 5]
 [9 8 6 4 5]
 [3 1 7 8 9]]

After:
[[0 0 0 4 5]
 [9 8 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 8 9]]
```

So, how would I do this in matlab?

It would be great if you could help me out here. Is there an equivalent to `argsort`, i.e., getting the e.g., 3 lowest values in a row so that I can set them to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach -

```
[m,n] = size(A); %// get size
[~,col_ind]= sort(A,2,'descend') %// sort the rows in descending order
A(bsxfun(@plus,(col_ind(:,3:end)-1)*m,[1:m]'))=0 %// get all indices other than 
             %// for top 2 values in each row and set those in A to zero
```

Please remember that with this approach the first match of maximum and second-maximum values would be kept.

Sample run -

```
A (Before) =
     1     2     3     4     5
     9     8     6     4     5
     3     1     7     8     9
     5     6     2     6     7

A (After) =
     0     0     0     4     5
     9     8     0     0     0
     0     0     0     8     9
     0     6     0     0     7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The note about "... first match of maximum and second-maximum..." - it's important to know, but for my application it wouldn't really matter since I have "real" (float) values

Comment: @SebastianRaschka I see, awesome then!